# In Sims Freeplay is it possible to get a divorce?

Tags: the-sims-freeplay

So in sims I had to marry two people to complete a quest but I didn't wanna marry THOSE TWO SIMS together. Is there a way to undo it???

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a divorce, you need the two Sims to be rude and complain to each other. After doing so, click on the interaction button again and there will be the option to divorce for a short amount of time.

Check out [this website](https://thegirlwhogames.blog/2016/01/16/the-sims-freeplay-getting-divorced/) for more detail.